# Replace AD with Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory

We are using a third-party IT provider that handles our network administration and domain accounts, but as part of moving to a different office and setting up new infrastructure, we are considering dropping that and using Azure Active Directory only.

Researching the topic online seems to indicate that Azure AD is not a complete replacement for on-premises Active Directory, as things like local resource access and group policies outside of Azure would be missing. However, we are moving towards using Azure for most things (file storage, etc), so that should be fine if we still have that functionality there.

Before finalizing the decision to go in that direction, we just need to be certain of a few things:

1) Is there a way to create a new account in Azure AD so that it can be used to login from any machine in the office, without having to create it locally first and then connect the two?

2) Is there a way to sync user data, such as user/desktop files, across any devices the account is used to log into?

3) Is it possible to have an office printer configured in Azure so that it can be used with an Azure AD login, completely independent on any on-premises setup (i.e, not Hybrid Cloud Print, which seems to require an on-premises network/AD to be joined with Azure AD)?

The goal is to be able to log in and work from any internet-connected device, whether in the office or at home, without needing to use a VPN and/or remote desktop, and forego on-premises AD administration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This is possible as long as the device is joined to Azure AD. Once the device is joined to Azure AD, then newly created cloud-only users can also login to the devices. 
   Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/concept-azure-ad-join
2. Enterprise state roaming should help in this aspect. It might not cover everything you are looking for but the important app-specific data and user settings are synced.
   Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/enterprise-state-roaming-overview
3. There is no direct solution from Microsoft for pure cloud scenarios. There are few 3rd party services offered for this.
   Ref: https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/azure/printix.64182edf-4951-40d5-91c8-733e1c896b70

Hope this helps.